# s///r; breaks syntax highlighter in Sublime

Tags: regex, perl, sublimetext3, syntax-highlighting

I have a Perl script and editor I'm using is Sublime.

After the below line of code, the syntax highlighter breaks.

`my $new = ($old =~ s/cat/dog/r);`

[image]

This is because of `/r`. But why?

How to tackle this problem or any alternatives?

Comment: Make sure you've configured the perl version in SublimeText to at least 5.14.

Comment: Use a smarter editor?

Comment: What build of Sublime Text are you using? It's under **`Help->About Sublime Text`**. I can't reproduce your issue, either with the [Build 3211 of Sublime Text 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2op0.png), or with the [latest dev build 4150 of Sublime Text 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNtGs.png). Build 4143 is the current regular (non-dev) build, and also doesn't have this issue. Do you have some plugin or other Perl syntax that you're using instead of the one that ships with Sublime, [this one](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/ModernPerl) perhaps?

Comment: @MattDMo Its `Version 3.1.1, Build 3176`.

Comment: The issue is solved when I use substitution like this - `my $new = ($old =~ s{cat}{dog}r);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a problem that exists in your version, v3.1.1 aka build 3176.

[image: Perl code in Sublime Text 3.1.1 is incorrectly highlighted]

This was fixed in v3.2 aka build 3200.

[image: Perl code in Sublime Text 3.2 is correctly highlighted]

Upgrading to the latest v3.x (v3.2.2) is covered under your current license, if you have one.

However, I strongly recommend updating to the latest version of [Sublime Text 4](https://www.sublimetext.com/download), which is Build 4143. I use the dev builds, which are slightly ahead of the public builds, and your code is highlighted correctly there as well:

[image: Perl code in Sublime Text Build 4150 is also correctly highlighted]

The code looks the same in Build 4143.

If you're a licensed user of Sublime Text you'll need a new license for ST4, but there are *so* many new features and improvements over the old version that it's definitely worth it to support the developers.

Answer (score 0):

The `r` modifier was added in 5.14. Your editor's highlighter apparently isn't aware of that change.

You could use the following instead:

```perl
my $new = $old;
$new =~ s/cat/dog/;
```

Combined:

```perl
( my $new = $old ) =~ s/cat/dog/;
```

Comment: I'm 99% sure the OP isn't using the Perl syntax that ships with Sublime - see my [comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76325288/s-r-breaks-syntax-highlighter-in-sublime#comment134594684_76325288). That notwithstanding, you shouldn't have to alter your code (i.e., not use the `r` suffix) to get around a bug in your editor, whatever the cause may be.

Comment: @MattDMo, I don't know anything about Sublime. But that wasn't required to provide a solution. It is possible that a better solution exists -- one that makes Sublime recognize the syntax -- and I'll gladly upvote it should it get posted.